# Difficulty in "expressing radical as square"

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I have to get from this expression:
$(4+2\sqrt3)(\sqrt{2-\sqrt3})$

To this expression:
$\sqrt2+\sqrt6$

I tried to square $(4+2\sqrt3)$ and put it inside the radical, so:
$\sqrt{(16+12+16\sqrt3)(2-\sqrt3)}$

but eventually I get to: $\sqrt{52+32\sqrt3-28\sqrt3-48}$ and therefore $\sqrt{8+4\sqrt3}$ which will give me $2\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}$

From there I stopped because it didn't seem that I was getting anywhere.

I checked on wolfram alpha and using the step-by-step solution the first thing that it does is:
"Express $2-\sqrt3$ as a square using $2-\sqrt3 = \frac{1-2\sqrt3+(\sqrt3)^2}{2}$ which is clearly correct and from there it is relatively easy to proceed to the solution.

So my questions are: (1) what is that does not work in my method of putting the squared expression inside the radical (2) where can I fond more information on how to express a radical as a square, is there a procedure (something similar to completing the square for example)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that you can compute square roots of numbers of the form $\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{d}}$. Indeed,
$$(x+y\sqrt{d})^2 = x^2 + dy^2 + 2xy\sqrt{d}. $$
We want $a = x^2 + dy^2$ and $b = 2xy$, so using $y = b/(2x)$, we get $a = x^2 + db^2/(4x^2)$, or $4x^4 - 4ax^2 + db^2 = 0$, which is a quadratic equation in $x^2$ whose solution is
$$ x^2 = \frac{4a\pm\sqrt{16a^2-16db^2}}{8} = \frac{a\pm\sqrt{a^2-db^2}}{2}. $$
For example, suppose we want to calculate $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}$, so $a=2$ and $b=-1$. The formula gives $x^2 = (2\pm\sqrt{4-3})/2 = (2\pm 1)/2=3/2,1/2$. This gives the solutions
$$ x + y\sqrt{3} = \pm \left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} - \sqrt{\frac{1}{6}} \sqrt{3}\right), \pm \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} - \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} \sqrt{3}\right).$$
Wolfram alpha suggests using the second solution:
$$
\begin{align*}
(4+2\sqrt{3})\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}} &= (4+2\sqrt{3})\left(-\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} + \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} \sqrt{3}\right) \\ &= -4\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} + 2\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot 3 + \left(4\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}-2\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\right)\sqrt{3} \\ &= 
2\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} + 2\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} \sqrt{3} \\ &= \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6}.
\end{align*}
$$
Of course, this is pretty ad hoc. However, this method will find an integral square root $\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{d}} = x+y\sqrt{d}$ if one exists, which could be helpful in other situations.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that $$\sqrt{8+4\sqrt{3}} = \sqrt{2+2\sqrt{12} + 6} = \sqrt{(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6})^2} = \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6},$$
as desired.  The trick is to write the $4\sqrt{3}$ term as twice a radical.

Comment: From the second expression it is very clear, but my problem is the step from the first to the second, it seems that it is like completing the square but the other way around. Maybe knowing that I should get to the given result I could eventually get it, but what if the result is not provided? It seems very easy but also very hard to get to the square of the sum :( Is there a generalized method? For example a+b -> (x+y)^2

Comment: I started posting this response before I saw that you had posted the answer.  I just wrote the $2\sqrt{12}$ term and then found two numbers that sum to 8 and multiply to 12.  So, in that sense, I suppose it is very similar to solving a quadratic.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that

$$4+2\sqrt3=(1+\sqrt3)^2$$
and

$$2-\sqrt3=\frac12(1-\sqrt3)^2$$
so the given expression is

$$\frac1{\sqrt2}(1+\sqrt3)^2(\sqrt3-1)=\sqrt2(\sqrt3+1)=\sqrt6+\sqrt2$$